# Is it possible to change width of a column in slickgrid programatically?

Tags: jquery, slickgrid

I tried grid.getColumns[index].width = <>. But, that doesn't resize the column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to re-apply the column settings to the grid after you have modified the column width.

```
$("#resize").click(function () {
    var cols = grid.getColumns();
    cols[0].width = 120;
    grid.setColumns(cols);
});
```

[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/qvRh5/)

Comment: This works, but the `.setColumns` method redraws the whole grid and is expensive. ~120ms in my setup. Is there a more surgical way to update col widths?

Comment: There are two internal methods that boost performance considerably. More here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/slickgrid/BBB-Qhg7TvU

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't work (anymore), can you fix it please?